# Matching records in different tables when they are not exactly the same SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One contains the name of a product and its strength i.e

Lustral Tablet 50Mg

The other table has the same product but written in a slightly different way:

LUSTRAL 50MG TABLETS

There could be other things in there that identify the product i.e "Dispersable" 
Is there any way to match these records up using sql? At the moment Im doing an inner join and a left(Column, 4) but that will only really match some names, not the strength etc.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: This is a pretty common problem, and not easy to solve. Has no general answer, but some common techniques.